# jQuery .load PHP into a Div -not working-

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

This is a fantastic resource and I have been using it extensively during my first website developing project.

I have static webpages that I want to maintain static but introduce WordPress (already installed and running on a /blog/ subdomain) onto the static homepage within a specified div.  I found the code:

```
<script typ="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
         $("#randomdiv").load("load.php");
    });
</script>
```

Which I modified from "#randomdiv" to "#myblog" and "load.php" to the "blog/index.php" file that WordPress added.  I'm also specifying  that I want #content from index.php.

```
<script typ="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
         $("#myblog").load("blog/index.php #content");
    });
</script>

<div id="myblog" class="grid_8">
"Loading..."
</div>
```

The kicker: **it worked for about an hour last night**.  I was styling the php in the CSS for my static page and it stopped working!  I have cleared everything and started over but no luck.  Where am I going wrong???

--Thank you for your responses--

Maybe someone can quickly and easily explain to me how .php works.  WordPress gives me about 15 .php files inside /blog/ and I assumed index.php was my ticket, but maybe not.  Still, lat night this worked.  I posted a new post and it appeared, I was styling it and everything.  Something has shifted and I can't find it.

Comment: "Not working" is *really* vague. If you have Google Chrome or Firebug for Firefox installed, check the JS console for errors. Post those.

Comment: Not showing any errors in the console on Google Chrome; in fact, it's not showing ANYTHING, and that is the root of my problems.  NOTHING displays.  Yet, it worked using that exact snippet of code last night.  My thinking is either: (1) my jQuery is wrong/not complex enough or (2) the index.php is not the right file to link to.  I'm sorry, I wish I could better troubleshoot this but I think I might be too close to it.

Comment: Is `blog/index.php` on the same domain, port and security (`http/https`) as your page?  Also, can you access `blog/index.php`?

Comment: Check for these little syntax errors on your code, like the wrong  attribute "typ".

Comment: Haha Karlisson it is correct in my code but I copied over from the blog that I got it from and she had mistyped it and apologized for it over there.  I do have that fixed though.

Comment: Blender: yes, it is on the same domain (I installed WordPress using Fantastico into the subdomain /blog/ from my main domain.  When I type the full extension into Google Chrome it replaces the address to "...com/blog/" instead of "...com/blog/index.php" but takes me exactly where I need to go.

Comment: If you have Chrome / Firebug, check the network tab to see if the request to "blog/index.php" is actually made and what it returns.

Comment: Nope, no request is made.  Why would that be?

Comment: Alright, I just got this from Chrome network tab:


zephyrdesigns.com
zephyrdesigns.com/blog
GET
(canceled)
undefined
http://www.zephyrdesigns.com/blog/index.php
Redirect
13B
0B
4.49s
0.0 days

Comment: FIXED IT!!!

Here was the issue:

WordPress was placing my index.php at http:// ... com/blog/index.php instead of http:/ /www ... com/blog/index.php.

I went into my WordPress dashboard, navigated to settings, and changed WordPress address (url) and site address (url) to include "www".

Viola, fixed!  THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR ALL YOUR HELP!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress was placing my index.php at http:/ / ... com/blog/index.php instead of http:/ /www ... com/blog/index.php.

I went into my WordPress dashboard, navigated to settings, and changed WordPress address (url) and site address (url) to include "www".

Answer (score -1):

Try `$('#myblog').load('blog/index.php')`. I you only need the `#content` element from the HTML loaded - consider requesting an another url that will return only the part of HTML code you need.

Also, probably, you broke your HTML when styling it, so jQuery does not find the `#content` element when HTML it is loaded with .load function - then it does not (and should not) show any error messages.

Comment: Now, again, this DID work last night.  I loaded just the #content tag from the div inside the index.php.  I feel like the definition of insanity here: trying the same thing over and over again expecting a different result.

Comment: I'm sorry to say so, but you're wrong. jQuery lets you to load only fragments of html. Take a closer look : http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments

Comment: Haha gion_13 I thought you were telling me I was wrong!  I was about to go get myself committed.  The above call did not work for me either.  If anyone has an extra minute (you all are so helpful I can't thank you enough) the site is live at www.zephyrdesigns.com.  I am trying to get the blog to load below the "divider1" div (the diagonal divider line below the three options.

Comment: Karevn: I'm trying to implement your approach keystroke for keystroke (and understand it as I go along).  I have erased all styling from my CSS to #myblog and I have not touched the original CSS document from index.php.  I'm still getting 0 network requests and no loaded content.

Comment: Alright, I just got this from Chrome network tab:


zephyrdesigns.com
zephyrdesigns.com/blog
GET
(canceled)
undefined
http://www.zephyrdesigns.com/blog/index.php
Redirect
13B
0B
4.49s
0.0 days