# Can't load wordpress block using jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm stuck with an ajax problem. I have a website, www.example.com, and I have an instance of wordpress in a subfolder, /webtv/. I am trying to load a block of the blog inside a dive in the main page. So, in my http://www.example.com/ I have the following code:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#blog-news').load( 'http://www.example.com/webtv/featured/' );
});
</script>
<div id="blog-news"></div>
```

If I load the URL http://www.example.com/webtv/featured/ pasting it directly on the browser, it works showing correctly the content; but the ajax call returns an empty content with no error.

Here the request and response headers of the AJAX call:

Request Headers

```
GET /webtv/featured/ HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html, */*; q=0.01
Origin: http://www.example.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36
Referer: http://www.example.com/?test=1
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: it-IT,it;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,es;q=0.2
```

Response Headers

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.6.2
Date: Wed, 07 Jan 2015 12:43:10 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Cookie
X-Pingback: http://www.example.com/webtv/xmlrpc.php
Link: <http://www.example.com/webtv/?p=2163>; rel=shortlink
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possibly duplicate of  <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232629/jquery-load-wordpress-php-into-a-div-solved>

Comment: I tryied with and without www, but the result remain the same.

Comment: Further comment: if I use iFrame in place of ajax, I can include it !